# Using 'grep' to find lines that contain all of three specified characters in any order

Tags: text-processing, grep

We have a document which contains lines and we have to find if [a|b|c] appears at least once in every line no matter which order.

For example:

Input:

```
abc
bca
cab
hhfdhdhfabjfdjdjff
acjfdjdfjdf
fhfhfhfabcjdfjdjfk
ahfhfbkjfjdjffc
```

Desired Output (the fourth line is absent since it only contains `a` and `b` but no `c`):

```
abc
bca
cab
fhfhfhfabcjdfjdjfk
ahfhfbkjfjdjffc
```

We are using Linux.

Comment: @terdon That many people want to answer a question does not mean it is a good one. The wording is bad (see the comments to wurtel's answer) and so was the formatting. Why upvote that? BTW: I don't consider your erasing the highlighting an improvement.

Comment: @HaukeLaging my edit was so that the text can be copied directly into a file for testing (I could have used quotes instead of codeblocks to keep the formatting, true). The previous version had lists which were harder to read and much harder to copy. Also remember that this is a new user who doesn't know the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) but gave all information needed to answer the question. Anyway, people's votes are their own but usually if you find a question interesting enough to answer, it is also good enough for an upvote.

Comment: @terdon: Note that [Why don't people upvote questions they answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/509/271976) addresses your last remark.

Comment: @G-Man yes, I know, we also have http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3133/ here. I left that comment (which I have now deleted) because at the time, there was a question with 0 upvotes and 4 answers. It was clear and easy to understand and only lacked formatting. All information needed to answer was provided, so I felt it was strange that nobody had upvoted it. Unfortunately, we have an issue with not upvoting questions on the site and that has been bugging me for a while which is why I made that comment.

Comment: See [Check if all of multiple strings or regexes exist in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762772/6862601).

Answer (score 26):

Pipe it:

```
grep a file | grep b | grep c
```

Comment: Simple and neat.

Comment: I'm surprised at the convoluted solutions below. This should be an obvious answer to anyone how knows about grep.

Comment: @Clearer it doesn't scale well at all

Comment: @ssdecontrol: Expand on why not?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I guess it depends on what you mean by "scale." I was thinking "scales to more letters" but I realize now people mean "scales to longer files."

Answer (score 8):

The `sed` advantage of `grep` easy to see in such examples

```
sed -n '/a/{/b/{/c/p;};}' file
```

or:

```
sed '/a/!d;/b/!d;/c/!d' file
```

Answer (score 7):

```
awk '/a/ && /b/ && /c/' file
```

Or with grep (which wouldn't scale well, though):

```
grep -e 'a.*b.*c' -e 'a.*c.*b' -e 'b.*a.*c' -e 'b.*c.*a' -e 'c.*a.*b' -e 'c.*b.*a'  file
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's compare all proposed solutions!

I have a text file `test.txt` of size ~230M. I'm on Mac Mini, updated to 10.10.

1) [`awk` solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182888/28659) by [Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32191/hauke-laging) (better not...):

```
$ time bash -c "awk '/a/ && /b/ && /c/' >> /dev/null"
19.51 real        19.23 user         0.20 sys
```

2) "bruteforced" `grep` by [Raghuraman R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100545/raghuraman-r) and [Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32191/hauke-laging) (better, but not really...):

```
$ time bash -c "grep -e 'a.*b.*c' -e 'a.*c.*b' -e 'b.*a.*c' -e 'b.*c.*a' -e 'c.*a.*b' -e 'c.*b.*a' test.txt >> /dev/null"
10.02 real         9.93 user         0.07 sys
```

3) [chained `grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182890/28659) by [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) (ok!):

```
$ time bash -c "grep a test.txt | grep b | grep c >> /dev/null"
1.61 real         3.08 user         0.29 sys
```

4) [`perl` solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182922/28659) by [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) (even better!):

```
$ time bash -c "perl -ne 'print if /a/ && /b/ && /c/' test.txt >> /dev/null"
0.83 real         0.75 user         0.07 sys
```

So, I think "chained grep" is ok, but you can also use Perl for even better performance.
I could not test `sed` approach, because the program provided by Costas does not work "as is" in mac os console.

BTW I'm no expert on benchmarking, sorry if I did something wrong.

Comment: This answer is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/are-answers-comparing-existing-answers-acceptable).

Comment: @dragn I'd suggest you add in credits for all the proposed solutions. E.g., where you currently just say "4) `perl`", say "4) [terndon](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon)'s [`perl` solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182922)".

Comment: agreed, I should have done that... I'll edit the post later, when I'll be at my PC

Comment: Your answer would have a much higher chance of being found via a search engine if you had made it into separate Q&A pair referring to the OPs question and the solutions you benchmarked, but clearly titling the Q as benchmark of text search strategies. That would also make it more easy for others to comment on the specifics or provide additional speed optimisation (e.g. what the effect of non-pattern `grep -F` might have), which is more difficult to do in comments on this answer (due to size and format limitations).

Comment: If comparing with `perl`, you'd need to pass `-Mopen=locale` to perl, or use `LC_ALL=C` for the other solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Through `grep` which accept `-P` (*Perl-regexp*) parameter.

```
$ grep -P '^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)' file
abc
bca
cab
fhfhfhfabcjdfjdjfk
ahfhfbkjfjdjffc
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Matches the start of a line
- `(?=.*a)` Only if the string going to be matched must contain a letter `a`
- `(?=.*b)` Must contain `b`
- `(?=.*c)` Must contain `c`

Comment: gnu grep accepts -P, to install it on a mac do "brew install grep", see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563092/is-gnu-greps-p-option-safe-to-use-in-production

Answer (score 4):

I would do this in perl instead:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /a/ && /b/ && /c/' file 
abc
bca
cab
fhfhfhfabcjdfjdjfk
ahfhfbkjfjdjffc
```

If you just want to check whether each line matches all three letters (without printing the line itself), you could do:

```
$ perl -lne '$k++ if /a/ && /b/ && /c/; 
 END{$k==$. ? print "yes" : print "no"}' file
```

Or

```
$ awk '(/a/ && /b/ && /c/){k++} END{if(k==NR){print "yes"} else{print "no"}}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is just a,b,c then we can use a mix of 'grep -o' and 'grep -e' option as below

```
grep -e "a.*b.*c" -e "a.*c.*b" -e "b.*a.*c" -e "b.*c.*a" -e "c.*a.*b" -e "c.*b.*a" file
```

You can also check already asked question at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Comment: @HaukeLaging your answer and this one were posted within 2 minutes of each other. It is safe to assume that you both wrote them at the same time and nobody copied from anyone.

Comment: @terdon My intention was not to claim this was copied from me. I have been on the other side often enough. But in such a case I would delete my answer if it was the later one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ $(grep a file | grep b | grep -c c) -eq $(wc -l file | cut -f1 -d' ') ]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

Comment: Are you sure you have understood the question correctly...?

Comment: The question was whether the combination of a, b and c occurs in *every* line. My snippet checks that... If the question was meant to be "show those lines where a, b and c occur" then the other answers answer that :)