# Is GNU grep's -P option safe to use in production?

Tags: grep, perl, gnu

The man pages for `grep` on Ubuntu 18.04 and CentOS 8 have this to say about the `-P` option for grep:

> -P, --perl-regexp
>                 Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).  This is  *experimental*  and  grep  -P  *may  warn*  of
>                 unimplemented features.

I have put emphasis on "experimental" and "may warn". Experimental implies it's not suitable for production. "may warn" implies that you could run into an unimplemented feature and `grep` could fail to warn you about it.

On older versions of `grep`, I have even seen the phrase "highly experimental" instead of just "experimental".

Is the `-P` option to GNU `grep` safe to use in production? Some of my bootstrapping scripts need certain perl features, so this option is quite useful to me when perl has not already been installed/included.

Comment: `grep -P` is of course absolutely non-portable; but if it works on your system, why not just use it? `grep -P` is based on the [`pcre`](https://www.pcre.org/) library, which is already used all over the place. IMLE it's `grep -E` which may get pathologically slow on some innocent regexes + inputs which `grep -P` will breeze through (but, unfortunately I don't have any examples at hand).

Comment: @mosvy Yes, I am aware that it is not portable. But it is available out of the box on CentOS 8 minimal which does not ship with perl. On FreeBSD I can use `fold` hacks to work with grapheme clusters (I was actually shocked that it's implementation of `fold` even supported grapheme clusters). I just like to know I have options available out of the box before I have started installing packages.

Comment: @mosvy sample you needed? https://askubuntu.com/q/960557/283843

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably a matter of taste.

Personally I would try to see if I could rewrite the regexp, so it only uses POSIX. If that is not possible I would use:

```
| perl -ne '/.../ and print' |
```

instead. This way I am sure it is supported, and it is clear what the error is if `perl` is not installed.

I *do* use -P for personal scripts (i.e. non-production).

The only time I think it *may* be justified to be used in production is if your scripts make a test that -P is supported and raise a clear error if it is not.